# Wiring an indoor motion sensor light

Tags: wiring, switch

How would I wire an indoor motion sensor light so to also be able to turn it on with a remote light switch?

Comment: Please edit your [original question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211355/i-want-to-put-a-motion-sensor-light-in-my-garage-and-also-be-able-to-turn-it-on) instead of asking a whole new one. Once you've edited it (to ask what you're asking here), people will retract their close votes and you'll get some good answers. Be sure to address the questions people have asked in the comments while you're editing it.

Comment: Also, if you'll take a minute to take the [tour], you'll get a better feel for how we work here - it's a bit different than most general discussion boards.